# Is there any language where 'emotion verbs' are more likely to behave like 'to fear' than 'to scare'?

Tags: semantics, linguistic-universals, valency

On the surface, these two verbs look like inversions of each other. With 'to fear', the experiencer of the fear is the subject, while the cause is the direct object. With 'to scare though', the subject is instead the cause and the direct object is the experiencer. However, they aren't fully equivalent. Both place the 'blame' of the fear on the subject. If you say you fear something, you acknowledge that its your own experience. If you say something like 'clowns are scary', then you're placing blame on clowns for causing the fear as if its something psionic ability all clowns project onto everyone.

English clearly leans more towards verbs behaving like 'to scare'. Its hard to find verbs that have an equivalent of 'to fear'. I wonder though is this a linguistic universal? Are there languages where most if not all such verbs behave like 'to fear'?

The reason I wonder this is because I've been wanting to make a conlang that does just this. However, this creates all manner of practical problems. For example, if its impossible to say that something is scary, then how would you define a horror movie? This has made me think that such a system is just impractical. Or is my perception of the world too influenced by 'the myth of universal experience' as I like to call it?

If there are languages that do this, then how do they handle things like my example? Like I said, my example seems to suggest that such languages just can't exist.

Comment: “It’s hard to find verbs that have an equivalent of 'to fear'.” — Really? I can think of quite a few other verbs expressing the experiencer’s emotion or reaction towards the cause that work like _fear_ (e.g., like, enjoy, adore; be indifferent to, not care [for/about]; hate, loathe, detest, abhor; dread, cringe [at/from], shudder [at]), and quite a few that work like _scare_ (exhilarate, please, tickle; disgust, sicken; frighten, terrify). Being able to describe both the experience and the effect seems useful – I’d venture it’s at least near-universal.

Comment: That said, it does occur to me that, at least at a quick glance, Mandarin leans more towards the _feel_ side than the _scare_ side of the fence. There are some pairs where both exist (such as 吓 _xià_ ‘scare’ vs 怕 _pà_ ‘fear’), but quite a lot of the ‘scare’ words don’t really exist as such in Mandarin, using instead causative constructions of ‘fear’ words (e.g., ‘it pleases me’ → ‘it makes me enjoy’; ‘it sickens me’ → ‘it makes me feel disgusted’).

Comment: You may be interested in the literature on psych(ological) verbs, see e.g. Pesetsky's *Zero Syntax*.

Comment: I do not understand the question. Lots of verbs behave differently from one another and their differences are given by their semantic traits/features. There is no equivalence at all between these two verbs. I don't think that to scare is an "emotion verb". That would be verbs like: fear, feel, experience, undergo, etc.

Comment: Scare is functionally a causitive.

Comment: It looks more like an inverse to me, minus the fact that the 'blame' is left on the 'subject', regardless of whether its the 'patient' or 'agent', assuming those terms could even be applied to these two roles.